# I can't understand UIScrollView behavior

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

I've read a lot of documentation but still don't really understand how that **UIScrollView** works.

I have an example where I use an **UINavigationViewController** with the **status bar** (little top bar with wifi, battery, etc., icons) and a **navigation bar** (with the "back" button).

As the first subview of the UINavigatioViewController's main view I have a UIScrollView. Inside it I have created several subviews that make it's contents size to be **500 points**.

In the "**viewDidLoad**" method I set the scroll view's "**contentSize**" equals to 500. But it doens't completely scroll down to show the last subview.

I read that I should add some points to the "**contentInset**" because of the "bars". I don't really know why. Isn't the scroll view inside the main view that is correctly framed? Why does it need to take the "bars" into account?

Anyway, I read that it should be like 64 points (44 navigation bar + 20 status bar). But it doesn't work.

The **"magic" number** (at least for me) is **84 points**. I must add that quantity to the content size (584) or use it as:

self.scrollView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,0.0,84.0,0.0); // AT THE BOTTOM!!

I'm really confused about this. Could anyone give a hand on understanding it?

Thanks.

```
self.scrollView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,0.0,84.0,0.0);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I have seen that because I made my ScrollView size bigger in Interface Builder in order to add new elements beyond the normal small visible size, it had a "frame" size near to 500 points.

I set it frame size to 416 (just to fit and cover all the visible space) and now with a content size of  500 points (without any additional inset values) it scrolls perfectly.

But I still don't understand the previous behavior...